# My "href" does not direct me to my route with double parameter - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a button where I have to return the customer id and the id of the payments made to a specific payment

```xml
<a
  href="{{ route('clients-credits-abono', ['clientid' => $client->id, 'creditid' => $creditclient->id]) }}"
  class="text-indigo-600 geosanslgbold py-2 px-3 rounded-md text-md border-2 border-indigo-600 hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600"
>
  View Pays
</a>
```

now, I have two routes, the first route shows me all the credits that belong to a client, in the second I show the payments made to the credit selected on the button.

```
Route::get('/clients/{clientid}/credits', [ClientCreditController::class, 'show'])->name('clients-credits-index');
Route::get('/clients/{clientid}/credits/{creditid}', [ClientPayController::class, 'show'])->name('clients-credits-abono');
```

but when I click the button I get an error:

**Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.**

if I put a number in the URL (test.test/clients/1/credits/4) it shows me the view

I want to assume that the error is when capturing the second parameter, since $client does give me the ID, but $creditid does not.

thanks in advance :D

Comment: If you do a dd() on $creditclient->id does it show a value?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a collection in your $client variable or $creditclient variable. Can you check them at the code below? You probably use ->get() at the end of your Eloquent chain so it will return you a collection.

```
<a href="{{route('clients-credits-abono', ['clientid' => $client->id, 'creditid' => $creditclient->id])}}" class="text-indigo-600 geosanslgbold py-2 px-3 rounded-md text-md border-2 border-indigo-600 hover:text-white hover:bg-indigo-600">View Pays</a>
```

You can read [more](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#collections) here.

Answer (score 0):

href have no problem.

`Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.`

this mean your object `$client` or `$creditclient` have no property `id` pls check following step :

1. check with `dd()` your above objects
2. check your controller that `$client` and `$creditclient` are compacted?

Comment: both are compacted